# Could rostopic pub the vector<KeyPoint> keypointsSelection type?

Tags: ros, c++, image, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hallo, experts,

i have a question about rostopic pub: i do something imageprocessing, than calculate the key-points of a image, and i want to use rostopic

> pub the vector KeypointsSelection

, that has been detected. but how could i myself define a msg ?
which format ? i just now std_msg, int8, float8, and so on... but how could i define a vector msg and pub it ??

thanks a lot.

Wang.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53264/could-rostopic-pub-the-vector%3Ckeypoint%3E-keypointsselection-type?/) by [Wang123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3658/wang123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See http://answers.ros.org/question/11105/how-to-pass-arrays-in-custom-messages/
and http://ros.org/wiki/msg

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2